# How to revert the second to last commit but not the last commit?

Tags: git

Say I have four commits `A-->B-->C-->D` but C was terribly misguided. How can I undo C without losing the changes from D? I understand the basic functionality of [git-revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) and [undoing commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/927386/5937428), but I can't figure out how (if it is even possible) to undo a specific commit (not the latest) without having to redo the changes that came after it.

Comment: That's what `git revert` does: it reverse-applies (i.e., reverts) some commit. Identify the bad commit `C`, run `git revert <thing that locates commit C>`, and Git applies a new commit to `HEAD` that undoes whatever was done in `C`. (This is in direct contrast to Mercurial, where `hg revert` means "restore some file(s)" and you use `hg backout` to undo a specific commit. Same revert verb, entirely different meaning.)

Comment: @torek - Wait, so it does not revert _to_ the specified commit (ie backup the history until that commit)? It only undoes the specified commit?

Comment: Exactly. In Git, that is. If you switch back and forth between Git and Hg it's really easy to goof this up (he says from experience :-) ). (BTW I think Hg's "backout" verb is better here; the problem with the verb "revert" is precisely what you've identified: is it "revert foo" or "revert TO foo"?)

Comment: @tbirrell just be aware C will still be in your commit history, as well as the new revert commit.  You're history willnot look like: `A->B->D`, but `A->B->C->D->E`

Comment: FWIW, the way to revert _to_ a specified commit in git is `reset`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Revert

The `git revert` command is designed to do exactly this.

```
git revert <hash for C>
```

This will create a new commit which reverses the change in C.

### Rewrite History

You can also rewrite history.  This is not generally recommended, and should only be used if you have a good reason to actually remove a commit from history (say, if it contains a password or something).

```
git rebase -i <hash for B>
```

In the editor, just delete the line with the hash for C.  The usual caveats apply if you have already pushed.

### Non-interactive

Technically, all of these options involve some kind of merge resolution which means they cannot truly be non-interactive. The only difference is the resulting history. With `git revert` you get a history that looks like this:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
                    ^
                    +--- reverts C
```

With `git rebase`, you end up with a history that looks like this:

```
A -> B -----------> E
```

You can of course just do `git rebase --onto B C`, instead of `git rebase -i`, but this is *still* an interactive process because you have to manually resolve any merge conflicts that can't be automatically resolved by the merge strategy.

Comment: also should note not to use rebase -i to reapply commits that have already been made public and pulled by others

Comment: If tiberrell  has already pushed his changes, then I think Ray's solution is better as it doesn't destroy history.  If the changes are only local, then rebase can also work in fewer commands (though is more prone to user error)

Comment: @jbu: Actually, that's incorrect—Ray's solution does destroy history.  It produces the same result as `rebase -i`, it just takes a roundabout path to get there.  The way to preserve history is with `git revert`.

Comment: you're right, I didn't read his commands carefully @DietrichEpp +1

Comment: Is there an answer that doesn't rely on -i interactive. An answer that "just does it"?

Comment: @PandaWood: Yes, `git revert` "just does it" and that's what you should be doing, it's already mentioned in the answer. You can do the equivalent `git rebase` operation as well, it's just more cumbersome and dangerous than the interactive version because with the non-interactive version, you have to copy and paste the right commit hashes or write `HEAD~2` `HEAD~1` correctly or you end up with missing bits of history, with `-i` it's much better because you can see the commit messages when you are manipulating them.

Comment: On Windows Git Bash, I ran `git rebase -i HEAD~2`, which then opened up a prepopulated commit message in Notepad++, and I was confused about what to do. Eventually I realized that I could cut and paste the 2 top lines to reorder the commits. When I closed Notepad++, the rebase finished (since there were no conflicts), and my commits were reordered. Then I ran `git reset --soft HEAD~1` to uncommit the now most recent commit (moving them back to staged).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming:

- A, B, C, and D are commit hashes (replace them with the hash wherever you encounter them)
- You actually want commit C gone from history permanently from master branch, not masked by a 'revert' commit.  If not the case, just use `git revert C`.

General steps

- Create a new branch off the main at commit B (this branch should look like A->B)
- Cherry pick the commit D to the new branch. (it should now be `A->B->D'`) it will get a new hash, I'll call it `D'`
- Switch to main branch
- Delete the C & D commits from the main branch ( main would look like `A->B` - Merge your new branch
  into main (main should now be `A->B->D'`)
- Delete your test branch.

Here's the code:

```
git checkout -b temp B
git cherry-pick D   
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD^^
git merge temp
git branch -D temp
```

Comment: This process looks like a manual version of `git rebase -i <B>`

Comment: @DietrichEpp I get nervous doing rebases :)

Comment: This way you get the complete branch in the temp to look at.  I guess you could rebase on the temp branch first and verify.

Comment: You're still doing a rebase either way, but you're doing it manually with 6 steps (maybe you forgot one?) instead of automatically with 1 step.

Comment: I get your point.  The only reason to be able to see the final result before changing the master branch, but you could do the rebase first on a test branch, verify it's as you desire, then do it on master.